# Handling "down" mnesia node if it contains most recent schema?

Tags: database, erlang, distribution, mnesia

I have two nodes- 1 and 2, both running. Node 1 goes down.

Node 2 carries on running- it is a remote node.

The computer for Node 2 is turned off. When I start Node 1, it knows Node 2 has the most recent schema.

What is the best strategy for handling this situation?

Comment: Can you please explain what you want the end result to be?  Should Node 1 wait for Node 2 and not accept any input?  Or do you want to accept new records, and merge the results later?  It's not clear to me what "handling the situation" means.

Answer (score 0):

How about this strategy?

1. node's mnesia should be connected.
2. When the whole system is shutdown by your specific command, not abort suddenly, one file of the file system will be marked.
   So if the file is not marked, the node is not clean.
3. Before a node starts up, the following check will be done:

if it is the first node,

3.1  if the above file is marked ok, the node will starts up normally.

3.2  if the above file is not marked ok, the node will not start up.

3.3. if the above file not exists, it is first-time-running, the mnesia database schema will be built up and then, start up.

if it is not the first node,

3.4. if the above file is marked ok, copy mnesia data from already-start-up node, then start up.

3.5. if the above file is not marked ok, delete schema and setup schema according to the already-start-up node, and copy data from already-start-up node, then start up.

3.6. if the above file not exists, it is first-time-running, the schema should be built according to 
already-start-up node, then start up.